# IDatabaseService dependency injection failed?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core, domain-driven-design

I am creating asp.net app using domain centric architecture.I have a problem in Application layer because of dependency injection unable to resolve `Demeter.Application.Interfaces.IDatabaseService` in `Demeter.Application.Events.Queries.QueryEvent.GetEventsListQuery`
. can someone help me to fix dependency injection?

> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type
>   'Demeter.Application.Interfaces.IDatabaseService' while attempting to
>   activate
>   'Demeter.Application.Events.Queries.QueryEvent.GetEventsListQuery'.

```
namespace Demeter.Application.Events.Queries.QueryEvent
{
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using Commands.CreateEvent;
    using Demeter.Application.Interfaces;
    using AutoMapper;
    using Domain;


    public class GetEventsListQuery : IGetEventsListQuery
    {
        public List<ListEventModel> Execute()
        {
            var events = this.databaseService.SelectEventsForList();

            //// Use AutoMapper to convert events (IEnumerable<Event>) to (List<ListEventModel>)
            //IMapper mapperConfig = this.mapperConfig.CreateMapper();

            //return Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Event>, List<ListEventModel>>(events);
            return null;
        }

        public GetEventsListQuery(IDatabaseService databaseService)
        {
            this.databaseService = databaseService;
            //TO-DO: Move this to mapper congigfration function 
            //this.mapperConfig = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
            //    cfg.CreateMap<Event, ListEventModel>();
            //});
        }

        private readonly IDatabaseService databaseService;
        private readonly MapperConfiguration mapperConfig;

    }
}

namespace Demeter.Application.Interfaces
{
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using Domain;

    public interface IDatabaseService
    {
        void InsertEvent(Event @event);
        void UpdateEvent(Event @event);
        void DeleteEvent(long recordId);
        IEnumerable<Event> SelectEventsForList();
    }
}
```

startup.cs form Service

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();

        this.Configuration = builder.Build();


    }

    public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        // Add framework services.
        services.AddScoped(provider =>
        {
            var connectionString = new SqlConnection(Configuration["ConnectionStrings:DevConnection"]);
            return connectionString;
        });
        // Register the Swagger generator, defining one or more Swagger documents
        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "My API", Version = "v1" });
        });
        services.AddMvc();

        services.AddTransient<IGetEventsListQuery, GetEventsListQuery>();


    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(this.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();


        app.UseMvc();

        // Enable middleware to serve generated Swagger as a JSON endpoint.
        app.UseSwagger();

        // Enable middleware to serve swagger-ui (HTML, JS, CSS etc.), specifying the Swagger JSON endpoint.
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");
        });
    }
}
```

}

this is the implementation of IDatabaseService in Persistance

```
namespace Demeter.Persistance.Services
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using Application.Interfaces;
    using Domain;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    using Dapper;

    public class DatabaseService : IDatabaseService
    {
        public void InsertEvent(Event @event)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void UpdateEvent(Event @event)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void DeleteEvent(long recordId)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public IEnumerable<Event> SelectEventsForList()
        {
            using (IDbConnection dbConnection = Connection)
            {      
                return dbConnection.Query<Event>("SELECT * FROM Event");
            }

        }

        public IDbConnection Connection
        {
            get
            {
                return new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            }
        }

        public DatabaseService(string connectionString)
        {
            this.connectionString = connectionString;
        }

        private readonly string connectionString;

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you registered `IDatabaseService` in your startup?

Comment: Where is your DI initialization code? As @DavidG said, have you registered the concrete type for `IDatabaseService` somewhere?

Comment: I don't think so.this is my first take of domain-centric architecture using asp.net CORE. can I ask how you can register IDatabaseService in your startup?

Comment: @NinjaDeveloper can you show us the concrete implementation of `IDatabaseService`?

Comment: @FedericoDipuma I added the implementation IDatabaseService

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to register `IDatabaseService` to the dependency injection engine of ASP.NET Core.

This is done inside the `ConfigureServices` method of your `Startup.cs` file.

By looking at your `DatabaseService` implementation it seems to depend on a connection string, but inside your `ConfigureServices` method you already provide a full `SqlConnection`.

To make everything work using DI you need to make some changes, using a connection directly in the constructor:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Add framework services.
    services.AddScoped<IDbConnection>(provider => new SqlConnection(Configuration["ConnectionStrings:DevConnection"]));
    // Register the Swagger generator, defining one or more Swagger documents
    services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "My API", Version = "v1" });
    });
    services.AddMvc();

    services.AddTransient<IGetEventsListQuery, GetEventsListQuery>();

    // Register your database service
    services.AddScoped<IDatabaseService, DatabaseService>();
}

public class DatabaseService : IDatabaseService
{
    public void InsertEvent(Event @event)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void UpdateEvent(Event @event)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void DeleteEvent(long recordId)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public IEnumerable<Event> SelectEventsForList()
    {
        _dbConnection.Query<Event>("SELECT * FROM Event");
    }

    public DatabaseService(IDbConnection dbConnection)
    {
        _dbConnection = dbConnection;
    }

    private readonly IDbConnection _dbConnection;

}
```

In the example I added the registration as "scoped" because it seems to have a direct dependency on the database connection (also declared as scoped).

This will also ensure that a single `IDatabaseService` is created and used per request.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't registered the concrete type for your `IDatabaseService` interface. Add a line like this:

```
services.AddTransient<IDatabaseService, DatabaseService>();
```

Without that, the DI framework doesn't know what to inject into the constructor for the `GetEventsListQuery` class.

I recommend reading [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection) on how dependency injection is done in .Net Core.